# Will hooking up a HF coil to a HF opamp nullify the induction in the coil?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to measure an oscillating magnetic field using a coil. Using a small self-spun coil, I can already measure very decent 100 KHz signals by hooking each end of the coil up to an oscilloscope.

I want to eventually pump the frequency up to 10 MHz. Using my extremely basic coil+oscilloscope setup I can already measure this for fairly strong oscillating magnetic fields but the fields that I'll be measuring will be much smaller. I can therefore not just hook my coil up directly to the oscilloscope anymore, but will need to amplify the signal.

My problem is as follows: if I want to push my signal through some filters, then those filters will invariably have some capacitance and resistance. Hooking up my coil to non-neglectable capacitances turns the whole thing into an electric oscillator, whose resonance frequency lies (for decent coils) far below 10 Mhz!

The solution I came up with was first passing the signal through an opamp, to "restart" the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDuRJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I do have some opamps that can handle 10 MHz signals. [The datasheet for the OPA6999](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1000000-1099999/001011355-da-01-en-IC_OPAMP_VFB_1GHZ_SG_OPA699ID_SOIC_8_TID.pdf) shows that it works just fine for these frequencies (page 7).

But won't I run into the same problem using this circuit? Won't the opamp introduce capacitance and inductance on the left side of the circuit that could significantly decrease my resonance frequency, unless I use a tiny coil?

Comment: Do you truly mean to have positive feedback as in your schematic?

Comment: Yes, this is the circuit for a voltage follower, right? What I mean to do is process the signal on the right hand side (i.e. by adding filters and/or active components) without interfering with the resonance frequency of the LHS coil.

Comment: @Heatherfield, a voltage follower has negative feedback, not positive feedback.

Comment: Also, on the OPA699 datasheet, notice the next bullet after it tells you the GBW product is 1000 MHz, it tells you it's stable for gain greater than 4 V/V. This means it isn't stable in follower configuration.

Comment: Shame... I should have noticed that. What about turning the thing into a V/V converter using the right side schematic in this image? https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp48.gif That could give me the right gain to make the circuit stable, without compromising on the input impedance I wanted. Do you think I could use such a circuit like that to keep the coil resonating, and still filter the signal that comes through?

Comment: Can you maybe find a spice model for the op-amp and get the input capacitance from the model? I don't think it will be more than 2pF or so. You can also add a resistor between the coil and op-amp to damp out any oscillations. I don't think it will be a large resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I designed and built a gain-of-600,000X amplifier for 100,000Hz, as part of beginning to evaluate magnetic beacons. Is this the level of gain you are considering?

There were 2 modules, each  with gain of 8 & 64 (analog-mux selectable), a gain of 1/2/4/8 to finetune the ADC loading, and a gain of 20X low-noise discrete amplifier.

And the frontend had 3:1 analog mux, to select X/Y/Z orthogonal coils.

As a teenager, I built many a 4/5/6/7/8 stage bipolar signal chain that oscillated until I learned to use extreme methods in VDD filtering. I call those "Local Batteries".

More recently, to evaluate silicon substrate crosstalk, I built AM radios ONCHIP with the sole purpose of downconverting a differential-signal (two probes into the substrate) to a few MHz IF and then boosting the IF by 40/80/100dB. This was oscillation-free in the 40 and 80dB modes; the 100dB setting did have some ringing but lacked overt oscillation.